# Netlogo sort variables

Tags: netlogo

I want to order these numbers in variables.
I tested with Ifs and didn't found the way of how to do it.

Then I tested with sort but it seems that i doesn't accept variables.

```
let ginyo00 [xcor] of coche 0     
let ginyo01 [xcor] of coche 1
let ginyo02 [xcor] of coche 2
let ginyo03 [xcor] of coche 3
output-print ginyo00
output-print ginyo01
output-print ginyo02
output-print ginyo03
output-print "====="
set maxv max (list ginyo00 ginyo01 ginyo02 ginyo03)
show sort [ginyo00 ginyo01 ginyo02 ginyo03]
```

[image: Error that shows]

I need a way of sorting this values and knowing which are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sort` primitive works on lists or agent sets, per [the docs](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort).

So you can use it with variables the same way you got the `max`, by using the `list` primitive to turn your variables into a list for `sort`:

```
show sort (list ginyo00 ginyo01 ginyo02 ginyo03)
```

You can also get this info without the intermediate variables:

```
let my-coches coches with [ who < 4 ]
ask my-coches [ output-print xcor ]
set maxv max ([ xcor ] of my-coches)
show sort ([ xcor ] of my-coches)
```

If what you actually want is the `coches` in sorted order instead of the values in order, you can use `sort-on` instead:

```
let sorted-coches sort-on [xcor] my-coches
show sorted-coches
```

Comment: Thank u <3 so much